# Как обработать закрытие фрагмента в активити

Tags: android, c#, android-fragment, xamarin, dialogfragment

Необходимо обработать закрытие `DialogFragment`, вызванного из `MainActivity`. После

```
dismiss();
```

нужно вызвать функцию обновления `ListView` в `MainActivity`. Только начал изучать разработку приложений на платформе `Xamarin`, находил только решения для `java`. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Просто наследуйте активность от интерфейса `DialogInterface.OnDismissListener`, в классе фрагмента создайте переменную этого слушателя и ее метод-сеттер. В `onCreateView` ставьте слушатель `setOnDismissListener(переменная)`

Comment: Кажется понял вас, спасибо!

Comment: Не за что, я в xamarin не умею работать, обьяснил вроде общими понятиями :)